# Can we create an ArrayList of parent nodes in firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I am a newbie in android development. I have searched google for answer to my problem but I could not find any that is why I am posting here.

Here is my db:
[image: My db]

I want to retrieve list/Array list of all the "keys" and nested objects(0,1,2). Something like this {key1{object1,object2,..}key2{object1,object2,..}}. I can also use custom title/text instead of random keys.

```
private val _getquestlist = MutableLiveData<List<userquestlist>>()
val getquestlist: LiveData<List<userquestlist>>
    get() = _getquestlist

 fun fetchusertest(uname:String,sub:String,mon:String){
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersTest").child(sub).child(mon)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
               if (snapshot.exists()) {
                   var questionlist = mutableListOf<Question>()
                   for (keysnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                       val keystring: String? = keysnapshot.key

                       FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersTest").child(sub).child(mon).child(keystring!!)
                           .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
                               override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                               }

                               override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                   
                                   for (questSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                                       val question = questSnapshot.getValue(Question::class.java)

                                       question?.let { questionlist.add(it) }
                                   }
                                   _getquestlist.value = questionlist
                               }

                           })

                   }
               }
                else _getquestlist.value=null
            }

        })
}
```

and this is Question class

```
data class Question(
    var question:String?=null,
    var opa:String?=null,
    var opb:String?=null,
    var opc:String?=null,
    var time:Long?=null
)
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: thank you for helping me. Android studio simply throws an exception of  "Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type userquestlist"

Comment: There's a child missing from your reference (-MUU .. mos). Try to add and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I could not get you. Do I have to create another child node under that key(-MUU..mos) to make this error gone? Can you please explain it through code?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a call to child("-MUU .. mos") in order to be able to read the underneath it. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you sir for your guidance. I have updated the code and now I am able to retrieve all the questions present under the key nodes but I want them in **group** not in the form of list. I want something like key1{Object1, Object2,..}, key2{Object1,Object2,..}.

Comment: Then simply iterate by the key and get the entire corresponding value, which is an object of type Question ;)

Comment: Sir can you assist me by writing the code?? How can I group these objects with respect to the key?